# SQL: Bucket calculated results

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, teradata

I'm pulling data from a table that contains transaction data, and want to get results that buckets data by average transaction size and accounts, and then as columns showing count of accounts, count of transactions sum of transaction size and average transaction size.  Essentially like this:

```
**raw data**                    
date        acct_nr    trans_am         
1/3/2017    1234       400          
1/20/2017   1234       700          
1/22/2017   1234       1100
1/22/2017   2345       300
1/23/2017   2345       800
1/24/2017   3456       1500
1/25/2017   4567       250
1/25/2017   4567       300
1/26/2017   4567       350

**current results**                 
month   tier            acct_ct trans_ct    trans_am    trans_avg
201701  a. >=250 <500   3       5           1600        320
201701  b. >=500 <1000  2       2           1500        750
201701  c. >=1000 <1500 2       2           2600        1300

**expected results**                    
month   tier            acct_ct trans_ct    trans_am    trans_avg (this column should be they key for bucketing, per account)
201701  a. >=250 <500   1       3           900         300
201701  b. >=500 <1000  2       5           3300        660
201701  c. >=1000 <1500 1       1           1500        1500
```

Currently this is the script I'm using which is giving me the **current results** instead of the **expected results**:

```
select
  cldr.year_month
  ,case
    when tran.tran_am >= 0 and tran.tran_am < 100 then 'a. >=0 <100'
    when tran.tran_am >= 100 and tran.tran_am < 250 then 'b. >=100 <250'
    when tran.tran_am >= 250 and tran.tran_am < 500 then 'c. >=250 <500'
    when tran.tran_am >= 500 and tran.tran_am < 1000 then 'd. >=500 <1000'
    when tran.tran_am >= 1000 and tran.tran_am < 1500 then 'e. >=1000 <1500'
    when tran.tran_am >= 1500 and tran.tran_am < 2000 then 'f. >=1500 <2000'
    when tran.tran_am >= 2000 and tran.tran_am < 2500 then 'g. >=2000 <2500'
    when tran.tran_am >= 2500 and tran.tran_am < 5000 then 'h. >=2500 <5000'
    when tran.tran_am >= 5000 and tran.tran_am < 10000 then 'i. >=5000 <10000'
    when tran.tran_am >= 10000 then 'j. >=10000'
    else 'z. other'
    end as trans_am_tier
  ,count(distinct tran.acct_id) as acct_ct
  ,sum(tran.tran_am) as trans_am
  ,count(tran.tran_id) as trans_ct
  ,(trans_am / trans_ct) as trans_avg

  from reports.tran as tran

  inner join reports.date as cldr on cldr.calendar_date=tran.tran_eff_dt
  inner join reports.acct as acct on tran.acct_id=acct.acct_id

  where tran.ext_tran_cd in ('ACHDD','ACHID','ACHRDD')
  and tran.tran_eff_dt between '2017-01-01' and '2017-04-30'
  and tran.prod_type = '4400'
  and acct.acct_stat <> 4
  and acct.dp_cust_nbr NOT IN (1007,1101)

  group by 1,2
  order by 1,2
```

I know it has to do with the fact that I'm bucketing **tran.trans_am**, and not **trans_avg**.  Would this be achieved by using subqueries?  Essentially calculating **trans_avg** first and then bucketing that?  Not sure how I would do that.

Essentially, the result should be "for every account number, count # of transactions and average the transaction amount for those transactions.  Then, based on that averaged transaction amount, place that account number with associated transaction count and average transaction size into one of the defined buckets, and then sum the total number of accounts per bucket".  So results should be grouped by account and by transaction tier, and bucketing should be determined by **trans_avg**.

By the way, I'm an analyst and only have read access to the DBMS.  Can't create temporary tables or any of that stuff.

Edits added to the raw data, current results and expected results to clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: How do you decide to which tier an account is assigned to? E.g. account `1234` can be counted in three tiers. And why there's no tier for the last row with an amount `100`?

Comment: Ah yes, you're absolutely right RE: the 100, overlooked that; will fix it.  Otherwise, it should be tiered based on the calculated average transaction amount, per account, per month.  So if an account has three transactions that average to $400, it should be tiered in that bucket, even if the three transactions are spread across multiple buckets if they were to be tiered separately.

Comment: But this is exactly what my answer provides :-)

Comment: @dnoeth I'm trying your query now, but I get an error: "Cannot nest aggregate operations".  Is this because of the sum(trans_ct) and sum(trans_am), which is summing a column that's already aggregated?  Or is it something else?

Comment: @dnoeth nevermind, I got it work.  The results are now more as expected.  Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your narration, you need to calculate the average per account first (using a Derived Table or CTE) and then count the number of rows per tier:

```
select
/*Then, based on that averaged transaction amount, place that account number with associated transaction count and average transaction size into one of the defined buckets, and then sum the total number of accounts per bucket*/
  cldr.year_month
  ,case -- no need to repeat the lower limit
    when trans_avg >= 0 and trans_avg < 100 then 'a. >=0 <100'
    when trans_avg < 250 then 'b. >=100 <250'
    when trans_avg < 500 then 'c. >=250 <500'
    when trans_avg < 1000 then 'd. >=500 <1000'
    when trans_avg < 1500 then 'e. >=1000 <1500'
    when trans_avg < 2000 then 'f. >=1500 <2000'
    when trans_avg < 2500 then 'g. >=2000 <2500'
    when trans_avg < 5000 then 'h. >=2500 <5000'
    when trans_avg < 10000 then 'i. >=5000 <10000'
    when trans_avg >= 10000 then 'j. >=10000'
    else 'z. other' -- this can only happen for trans_avg < 0
    end as trans_am_tier
   ,count(*)
   ,Sum(trans_ct)
   ,Sum(trans_am)
from
 (
    select
    /*for every account number, count # of transactions and average the transaction amount for those transactions
    */
       cldr.year_month
      ,acct.acct_id
      ,sum(tran.tran_am) as trans_am
      ,count(tran.tran_id) as trans_ct
      ,(trans_am / trans_ct) as trans_avg -- why not a simple avg(trans_am)??
    from reports.tran as tran

      inner join reports.date as cldr on cldr.calendar_date=tran.tran_eff_dt
      inner join reports.acct as acct on tran.acct_id=acct.acct_id

    where tran.ext_tran_cd in ('ACHDD','ACHID','ACHRDD')
      and tran.tran_eff_dt between '2017-01-01' and '2017-04-30'
      and tran.prod_type = '4400'
      and acct.acct_stat <> 4
      and acct.dp_cust_nbr NOT IN (1007,1101)

    group by 1,2
 ) as dt
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks.  Had to modify your query slightly as I got a "Cannot nest aggregate operations" error at first.  I fixed this by adding an alias to the sum(trans_ct) and sum(trans_am) which seemed to fix it.  Also added another GROUP BY statement at the end as part of the outer select statement

Comment: Yep, the 2nd GROUP BY was missing, but I dont know why it complained about nesting aggregates (might be based on your actual query).

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the approach you want is to aggregate the data first and then assign the aggregated records to tiers based on `trans_avg` rather than `tran_am`. You're also correct that you can achieve this with a subquery, like so:

```
-- Create sample data.
create table [tran]
(
    tran_id bigint,
    acct_id bigint,
    tran_am bigint,
    tran_eff_dt date
);
insert [tran] values
    (1, 1234, 400, '20170103'),
    (2, 1234, 700, '20170120'),
    (3, 1234, 1100, '20170122');

create table calendar
(
    calendar_date date,
    year_month char(6)
);
insert calendar values
    ('20170103', '201701'),
    ('20170120', '201701'),
    ('20170122', '201701');

-- Aggregate transactions first, then assign to a tier.
select
    TransactionsByMonth.year_month,
    case
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 0 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 100 then 'a. >=0 <100'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 100 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 250 then 'b. >=100 <250'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 250 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 500 then 'c. >=250 <500'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 500 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 1000 then 'd. >=500 <1000'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 1000 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 1500 then 'e. >=1000 <1500'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 1500 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 2000 then 'f. >=1500 <2000'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 2000 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 2500 then 'g. >=2000 <2500'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 2500 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 5000 then 'h. >=2500 <5000'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 5000 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 10000 then 'i. >=5000 <10000'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 10000 then 'j. >=10000'
        else 'z. other'
    end as trans_am_tier,
    TransactionsByMonth.acct_ct,
    TransactionsByMonth.trans_am,
    TransactionsByMonth.trans_ct,
    TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg
from
    (
        select
            calendar.year_month,
            count(distinct [tran].acct_id) as acct_ct,
            sum([tran].tran_am) as trans_am,
            count([tran].tran_id) as trans_ct,
            sum([tran].tran_am) / count([tran].tran_id) as trans_avg
        from
            [tran]
            inner join calendar on [tran].tran_eff_dt = calendar.calendar_date
        group by
            calendar.year_month
    ) TransactionsByMonth;
```

Note that I've omitted some of the joins and `WHERE` clause expressions from your original query just to simplify the task of re-creating your data set. I also changed the definition of the `trans_avg` column because my DBMS won't allow me to define one element in the `SELECT` list in terms of aliases defined earlier in the list. (I don't have Teradata.)

Another option would be to use a [common table expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression), or CTE. While there are things you can do with a CTE that you can't do with a subquery (like create a recursive query), in this case it's really just a matter of taste. I like CTEs better because I find them easier to read, especially in cases where you need multiples; multiple nested subqueries get confusing in a hurry. Here's what the CTE approach would look like:

```
with TransactionsByMonth as
(
    select
        calendar.year_month,
        count(distinct [tran].acct_id) as acct_ct,
        sum([tran].tran_am) as trans_am,
        count([tran].tran_id) as trans_ct,
        sum([tran].tran_am) / count([tran].tran_id) as trans_avg
    from
        [tran]
        inner join calendar on [tran].tran_eff_dt = calendar.calendar_date
    group by
        calendar.year_month
)
select
    TransactionsByMonth.year_month,
    case
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 0 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 100 then 'a. >=0 <100'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 100 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 250 then 'b. >=100 <250'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 250 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 500 then 'c. >=250 <500'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 500 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 1000 then 'd. >=500 <1000'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 1000 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 1500 then 'e. >=1000 <1500'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 1500 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 2000 then 'f. >=1500 <2000'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 2000 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 2500 then 'g. >=2000 <2500'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 2500 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 5000 then 'h. >=2500 <5000'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 5000 and TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg < 10000 then 'i. >=5000 <10000'
        when TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg >= 10000 then 'j. >=10000'
        else 'z. other'
    end as trans_am_tier,
    TransactionsByMonth.acct_ct,
    TransactionsByMonth.trans_am,
    TransactionsByMonth.trans_ct,
    TransactionsByMonth.trans_avg
from
    TransactionsByMonth;
```

As I mentioned, I don't have Teradata installed, but I think everything here should be standard SQL, so hopefully it works for you, or at least leads you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this query (the CTE version), but then all results just get grouped into one bucket: h. >=2500 <5000.  It does not break it down into all the different buckets, eventhough I'm sure there is more than just one bucket the results can be grouped in.

Comment: I was unclear on what you wanted. The expected results given in your question show only a single record, with all three rows grouped together. But the last paragraph of the question talks about grouping by account, whereas your sample query didn't do that, hence my uncertainty. I just went with the data set you gave. Maybe edit your question with a data set that includes multiple accounts so we can see what you expect to have happen then?

Comment: Updated my question and the raw data/current results/expected results to clarify what I'm looking for.